# Array Literal with Object Literal inside Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var insurance = [
  {
    id: 'John',
    policy: [
      {name: 'geico', cost: 400},
      {name: 'nationwide', cost: 500},
      {name: 'maine', cost: 550},
      {name: 'litty', cost: 450}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Chris',
    policy: [
      {name: 'emran', cost: 400},
      {name: 'kite', cost: 500},
      {name: 'tile log', cost: 450},
      {name: 'seatle ins', cost: 600},
    ]
}
];
function loop() {
 var all;
 for (var i in insurance){
  all.push(insurance[i].id + " " + insurance[i].policy[i].name +  " " + insurance[i].policy[i].cost);
 }
 return all;
}
console.log(loop());
```

I am stuck trying to get access of values from properties.
Answer should be like

```
John geico 400
John nationwide 500
```

and continue till it goes through every id and every policy. 
I know how to get to the answer by using

```
console.log(insurance[0].id + " " + insurance[0].policy[0].name +  " " + insurance[0].policy[0].cost);
console.log(insurance[0].id + " " + insurance[0].policy[1].name +  " " + insurance[0].policy[1].cost);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate the outer array `insurance` array, and the inner `policy` array. You can convert the outer objects to arrays using nested `Array.prototype.map()`, and then flatten the sub arrays to a single array by applying `Array.prototype.concat()`:

```js
function loop(arr) {
  return [].concat.apply([], arr.map(function(item) {
    return item.policy.map(function(policy) {
      return item.id + " " + policy.name + " " + policy.cost;
    });
  }));
}

var insurance = [
  {
    id: 'John',
    policy: [
      {name: 'geico', cost: 400},
      {name: 'nationwide', cost: 500},
      {name: 'maine', cost: 550},
      {name: 'litty', cost: 450}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'Chris',
    policy: [
      {name: 'emran', cost: 400},
      {name: 'kite', cost: 500},
      {name: 'tile log', cost: 450},
      {name: 'seatle ins', cost: 600},
    ]
  }
];

console.log(loop(insurance));
```

Or an even shorter code if you use ES6 arrow functions, array spread, parameter destructuring, and template string:

```js
const loop = (arr) => [].concat(...arr.map(({ id, policy }) =>
  policy.map(({ name, cost }) => `${id} ${name} ${cost}`)
));

const insurance = [
  {
    id: 'John',
    policy: [
      {name: 'geico', cost: 400},
      {name: 'nationwide', cost: 500},
      {name: 'maine', cost: 550},
      {name: 'litty', cost: 450}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'Chris',
    policy: [
      {name: 'emran', cost: 400},
      {name: 'kite', cost: 500},
      {name: 'tile log', cost: 450},
      {name: 'seatle ins', cost: 600},
    ]
  }
];

console.log(loop(insurance));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `all` as array.

```
  var all = [];
  //      ^^^^
```

And to iterate policy as well.

You can return the result with an outer [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and an inner 
[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var insurance = [{ id: 'John', policy: [{ name: 'geico', cost: 400 }, { name: 'nationwide', cost: 500 }, { name: 'maine', cost: 550 }, { name: 'litty', cost: 450 }] }, { name: 'Chris', policy: [{ name: 'emran', cost: 400 }, { name: 'kite', cost: 500 }, { name: 'tile log', cost: 450 }, { name: 'seatle ins', cost: 600 }] }];

function loop() {
    return insurance.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(a.policy.map(function (b) {
            return a.id + " " + b.name + " " + b.cost;
        }));
    }, []);
}

console.log(loop());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one .

```
insurance.forEach(function(item, index) {
  Id = item.id;
  item.policy.forEach(function(item1, index1) {
    console.log(Id + " " + item1.name + " " + item1.cost)
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution helps :)!

```js
var insurance = [
  {
    id: 'John',
    policy: [
      {name: 'geico', cost: 400},
      {name: 'nationwide', cost: 500},
      {name: 'maine', cost: 550},
      {name: 'litty', cost: 450}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Chris',
    policy: [
      {name: 'emran', cost: 400},
      {name: 'kite', cost: 500},
      {name: 'tile log', cost: 450},
      {name: 'seatle ins', cost: 600},
    ]
}
];
function loop() {
  
var info1;
var into2;
var all = []
for(var i in insurance){
  var user = insurance[0].id;
  //console.log(user)
   for(var j in insurance[0].policy){
      info1 = user + " "+ insurance[0].policy[0].name + " " + insurance[0].policy[0].cost;
      info2 = user + " "+ insurance[0].policy[1].name + " " + insurance[0].policy[1].cost;
   }
 }
 all.push(info1, info2);

 return all;
}

console.log(loop());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var insurance = [
  {
    id: 'John',
    policy: [
      {name: 'geico', cost: 400},
      {name: 'nationwide', cost: 500},
      {name: 'maine', cost: 550},
      {name: 'litty', cost: 450}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'Chris',
    policy: [
      {name: 'emran', cost: 400},
      {name: 'kite', cost: 500},
      {name: 'tile log', cost: 450},
      {name: 'seatle ins', cost: 600},
    ]
}
];

  
insurance.map(function(b){ 
    return b.policy.map(function(a){console.log( b.id,a.name,a.cost);});
  });
```